# using eldap library in elixir

Tags: ldap, elixir

I have a trouble using erlang's eldap module in elixir. I had no problem with opening connection and using simple_bind/3, but now I want to add a new user. I tried it in erlang and it was just fine

```
7> eldap:add(H,"cn=test1,dc=example,dc=com", [{"objectclass",
             ["person"]}, {"cn", ["Test1"]},{"sn", ["Testov"]}]).
ok
```

But in elixir I can't make it work

```
iex(34)> :eldap.add(h, "cn=test1,dc=example,dc=com", [{"objectclass",["person"]},
                    {"cn", ["Test1"]},{"sn", ["Testov"]}])

** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :eldap.add/3
eldap.erl:183: :eldap.add(#PID<0.169.0>, "cn=test1,dc=example,dc=com",
[{"objectclass", ["person"]}, {"cn", ["Test1"]}, {"sn", ["Testov"]}])
```

I tried (handle, [DN], [attr]) but it throws an error

```
** (throw) {:error, :attribute_values}
eldap.erl:197: :eldap.add_attrs/1
eldap.erl:187: :eldap.add/4
```

Atoms as names of attributes didn't work either.

Do you have any insights, thoughts or something else that could help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `char lists` instead of `string`? `:eldap.add(h, 'cn=test1,dc=example,dc=com', [{'objectclass',['person']},
                    {'cn', ['Test1']},{'sn;, ['Testov']}])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the reason you got `FunctionClauseError` is `:eldap.add/3` expecting erlang string as arguments which is elixir charlists. The following should work:

```
:eldap.add(h, 'cn=test1,dc=example,dc=com', [{'objectclass',['person']}, {'cn', ['Test1']},{'sn;, ['Testov']}])
```